# Python/Flask/HTML <plaintext> Output is adding spaces

Tags: python, html, flask

So i am using python flask to output the result of a script to plain text on a webpage.  When I print the function from CLI the output looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

However when it is on the website it looks like this:

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

The output HTML file looks like this:

```
<plaintext>
{% for rows in report %}
    {{rows}}
{% endfor %}
```

Im really not great at HTML, but is there a way to remove the new lines that are added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `<plaintext>` is obsolete. Use `<pre>` instead. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/plaintext
2. The `rows` variable you used may contains line breaks already. And you don't need to use for loop if you just want to output every line in `report`. Try this:

   ```
   <pre>{{ ''.join(report) }}</pre>
   ```
3. Considering the control structure. You can use Jinja2's [whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control) feature to avoid extra spaces (and line breaks):

   ```
   <pre>
   {% for row in report -%}
       {{ row }}
   {%- endfor %}
   </pre>
   ```

Comment: Thank you!  This works perfectly, sorry for the duplicate, I did not find that one when I searched.